# Facebook profile uploading using ios swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I want to Upload facebook's profile picture using my app. I have used `FBSDKProfileExpressionKit` and following code to achieve profile upload.

`FBSDKProfileExpressionSharer.uploadProfilePicture(from: image, metadata: nil)`

It is redirecting me on facebook's profile upload screen but my image is not being uploaded as profile picture. Is there any other way to achieve it?

Thanks!

Comment: You can not set user profile pictures via API. Getting the upload dialog triggered where the user can then choose whether they want to set the new image as their profile pic is the most you can achieve.